# iOS: Is it possible to push an update for a side-loaded development app?

Tags: ios

I am side-loading a development version of an app to help qa changes.  Is it possible to have future updated versions of the development app pushed to my phone when the developer finishes a new build?

To be clear, this is NOT for the version in the app store -- this is for a development version we are hosting on our own servers, for which my device UDID has been given permission.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible.

The best you can do, is notifying (email, ...) your tester(s) and provide a link to download the app update.
This update is really considered as an update, overwriting the previous version in your tester phone.

But you cannot push. Even if you know UDID.

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm new to iOS dev -- thanks!

Comment: I can't yet, hold your horses :)